# CloudFormation template to update the IAM Role's policy

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a CloudFormation template that takes the IAM role's ARN as the input and updates its policy assigned to it to add more privileges?I tried to work with the CloudFormation designer but it is very confusing and not straightforward,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with a template such as this:

```
Description: Add policy to existing role

Parameters:

  MyExistingRoleName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the Role you want to add a policy to

Resources:

  MyNewPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: "my-new-policy"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
          Resource:
            - "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref MyExistingRoleName
```